# Return a collection of model as an output

Tags: vb.net, collections, model

I am simply trying to create an function to return a set of user. But, in order to be able to add the item later to a collection I used arrayList, but at last I am getting an error of  `Type ArrayList cannot be converted to 1-Dimensional array of Users`

Here is my Code:

```
Function getDoctorsList() As Users()
    Dim userCollection As New ArrayList
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM '" + _tblName + "' WHERE usertype = 'doctor'"
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = dbHelper.ExecuteAndGetReader(sql)
    While dr.Read
        Dim user As New Users
        user.Id = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("id")), 0, dr("id"))
        user.UserName = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("username")), "", dr("username"))
        user.UserNin = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("user_nin")), 0, dr("user_nin"))
        user.UserType = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("usertype")), "", dr("usertype"))
        user.Password = IIf(IsDBNull(dr("password")), "", dr("password"))
        userCollection.Add(user)
    End While
    Return userCollection
End Function
```

How to solve such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either let your method return an `ArrayList`:

```
Function getDoctorsList() As ArrayList()
```

create an `Array` out of your `ArrayList`:

```
Return userCollection.ToArray()
```

or, the best solution, let your method return an `IEnumerable(Of User)`

```
Function getDoctorsList() As IEnumerable(Of User)
```

you should also use a `List(of User)` instead of a `ArrayList` instead, since it is type safe (and clearer) and it also implements `IEnumerable(Of User)`.

---

**Edit**

Example using `IEnumerable(of Users)` and [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx):

```
Function GetDoctorsList() As IEnumerable(of Users)
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM '" + _tblName + "' WHERE usertype = 'doctor'"
    Dim table = new DataTable()
    table.Load(dbHelper.ExecuteAndGetReader(sql))
    Return (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            select new User() With
            {
               .Id = row.FieldOf(Of Integer)("id"),
               .UserName = row.Field(Of String)("username"),
               .UserNin = row.Field(Of Integer)("user_nin"),
               .UserType = row.Field(Of String)("usertype"),
               .Password = row.Field(Of String)("password")
            }).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: And how will i add to this IEnmerable(Of User)

Comment: If you later on really need to add other Users to the collection outside of your method, you can create a `List` out of the `IEnumerable(Of User)` as easy as `Dim list = new List(of User)(getDoctorsList())` or let your method return a `List(of User)`, but I would stick with `IEnumerable(Of User)`, since it is the cleanest apporach IMHO

Comment: Actually I am pretty beginner on this, so I dont know to use IEnumerable. Can you add an example on your answer?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now can you tell, How to define a DropDownList to use this list and how to specify the field for Text and value?

Comment: I added an example of how to use the DataRowExtensions, which come in handy if you're working with stuff like this. maybe you find it usefull.

Comment: Better ask another question for this, since it is an entire other topic